# Почему не работает условие? php

Tags: php

```
$res = 'https://site.domian/path/fail';
$resl = end(explode('/', $res))=="fail"?true:false;
```

ну все равно выдаёт false! Как так получается?

Comment: end нельзя натравливать на результат функции. сохраните в переменную, будет работать `$temp = explode... end($temp)`

Comment: С нотисом но работает https://3v4l.org/CqEc2

Comment: @splash58 Можете по подробней я все равно не понял)

Comment: @u_mulder Интересно, может это в семерке? посмотрю попозже, мне казалось, что валится

Comment: @splash58 в евале только семерка да.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если быть точнее, то ваш код будет возвращать **NOTICE**: "Only variables should be passed by reference".
Как и написал splash58 в комментариях к вашему вопросу, вам нужно занести результат функции `explode()` в переменную:

```php
$array = explode('/', $res);
$result = (end($array) == 'fail');
```

Также вам необязательно указывать в тернарном операторе 'true' и 'false', т.к. условие само по себе возвращает значение типа boolean.

Comment: Код будет возвращать не только notice, но еще и результат правильный.

Comment: нотис не возвращается, а выдается или генерируется (или как хотите назовите). возвращается только результат функции.

Comment: Уже вехал что при таком варианте end(explode('/', $res)) , end подхватывает функцию а не её результат.

Comment: @u_mulder, фреймворки, как правило, перехватывают все Notices и Errors, и код дальше выполняться не будет.

Comment: Здесь нет ни одного упоминания о фреймворках.